# Trouble reading CSV file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, utf-8

I'm working on a data analysis project & I wanted to read data from CSV files using pandas. I read the first CSV file and It was fine but the second one gave me a UTF 8 encoding error. I exported the file to csv and encoded it to UTF-8 in the numbers spreadsheet app. However, the data frame is not in the expected format. Any idea why?
[image: code in Jupyter notebook]

the original CSV file in numbers
[image: the original CSV file in numbers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your file is semicolon separated not comma separated.
To fix this you need to add the `sep=';'` parameter to `pd.read_csv` function.

```
pd.read_csv("mitb.csv", sep=';')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the correct delimiter, in this case ";", to read the csv.

```
mitb = pd.read_csv('mitb.csv', sep=";")
```

Answer (score 1):

The file is semicolon-separated and also decimal is comma, not dot

`df = pd.read_csv('mitb.csv', sep=';', decmal=',')`

And [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)